# How to clear data in particular column excepting Headers Using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wants to clear data which is shown red color. 
i tried with below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents


End Sub
```

i am not getting any idea please help me.

[image: data to be clear is]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C2:D" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
    .Range("L2:M" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
End With
```

Assuming that your data is located on `Sheet1`.